# How to detect which div is active on change?

Tags: jquery, pager

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<div class=”wrapper active”>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class=”wrapper”>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class=”wrapper”>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class=”wrapper”>
    <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class=”wrapper”>
    <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Each `wrapper` div has a full screen height and width.  As the user scrolls from one full screen `wrapper` to the next, the `active` class will toggle to the current div showing in the viewport.

These `wrapper` divs are generated dynamically from the CMS.  I need to be able to get a count of the total `wrapper` divs and then determine which one has the `active` class.  This will allow me to use jQuery to update the pager to correspond to the `active` child.

Here is my attempt to get on track with this:

```
$('body').each(
    function() {
        var numberOfDivs = $('.full-screen-wrapper', $(this)).length);
    }
);

$(".pager span:nth-child(1)").addClass("activenav");
```

I know this code needs some love, but I am in need of some direction on how to solve it.  As you can see, I am adding the `activenav` class to the first item in the list.  I need this `nth-child` value to equal the current `wrapper active` div.

Just to help clear up any confusion.  Here is the structure of the `pager`:

```
<ul class="pager">
    <span class="activenav">•</span>
    <span class="">•</span>
    <span class="">•</span>
    <span class="">•</span>
    <span class="">•</span>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I just need to get the right count of how many divs are before the `active` class so that I can update the `nth-child` value to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$('.wrapper.active').index()` to get position of active. Then you can use your nth-child

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple approaches you could take. I generally refer to this functionality as a "scrollspy" which goes back to MooTools' scrollspy as far as I recall. You're using jQuery so you might consider using [jQuery-scrollspy](https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy). There's also a scrollspy included in Bootstrap if you're using that by any chance.

You could also just write this from scratch. I'd do it by keeping up with the top and bottom offset-from-top of each div, then comparing that to the window's offset from Y. If you are between the high and low value for a particular div then that one is active. I have demonstrated that strategy [on CodePen](http://codepen.io/ryanburnette/pen/MYVppm).

```
function getDivPositions() {
  var positions = []
    ;

  $("body > div").each(function () {
    positions.push({
      el: $(this)
    , top: $(this).offset().top
    , bottom: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()
    });
  });
  return positions;
}

function setActive() {
  var currentPosition
    , divPositions
    ;

  currentPosition = window.pageYOffset;
  divPositions = getDivPositions();

  divPositions.forEach(function (d) {
    if ( currentPosition >= d.top && currentPosition <= d.bottom ) {
      d.el.addClass("active");
    }
    else {
      d.el.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
}

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
  setActive();
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a from scratch approach rather than a plugin.  I already have the toggle working for the `active` class on the `wrapper`.  So really I just need to find out which `wrapper` has the `active` class.  So if the third one is `active` then the third pager will get the `activenav` class.  I am currently looking into build a jQuery object to help solve this.

Comment: Give me a few minutes I can give you a draft on CodePen.

Comment: Take a look http://codepen.io/ryanburnette/pen/MYVppm It's not the best possible way, but it's the fastest way to demo it. And it should work for your needs. It does require that you have a single column of divs that are relevant. And you'll need to [polyfill forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you want old browser support.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts on this question.  This code snippet should serve as a great reference, but in the end the solution offered by farincz worked for my issue.

Comment: I must not have understood your question. I still had fun writing a bit of JavaScript.